# Server error 500 when executing simple "Hello, world" in Python XAMPP

Tags: python, xampp, http-status-code-500

I am trying to execute this code:

```
#!C:\python-3.7.0-embed-amd64\python.exe

print('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print('\r\n')
print('Hello, World!')
```

and I got this error:

> Server error!
>   The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.6

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is no white space or tab characters before the shebang (#!).  That was my issue.

It must be at the first character position of the file.

Comment: This was the issue for me.